# csh script error: Variable name must begin with a letter

Tags: shell, csh

```
set number = $<
set n = @ $number % 2
```

I am new to csh. I am simply trying to understand basic stuff.
I am getting this error: `set: Variable name must begin with a letter.`
How do I fix it?

Comment: The C **shell** has absolutely nothing to do with the C language! Read the tag info before adding unrelated tags!

Comment: I think there can't be spaces around the `=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `@` command incorrectly. In order to evaluate and store the result of an expression:

```
set number = $<
@ n = ($number % 2)
```

But Csh is particularly painful to use as a scripting language -- you are better off using bash or Python instead. I strongly recommend reviewing these:

- [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/csh)
- [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt).